# SnowSQL crashing in windows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have installed snowsql-1.2.2.windows_x86_64. Installation is successful however snowsql.exe crashes when opened.

Few steps i checked below:
a. PATH seems to be correct,
b. Tried running from command prompt , still it crashes.

Could you please help

Comment: Can you copy the error message you get when you start from the console?

Comment: I didnt get any error messages. When i run in command prompt, it pops up and crashes in a second.

Comment: Weird. Can you look at the log files in your the .snowsql directory inside your home directory?

Comment: do you mean the log_bootstrap file in .snowsql folder ? Its a 0 byte file.

Comment: Yes, that one or the "log" file should have details. If they don't, I suspect something's fundamentally odd with your system - maybe antivirus preventing execution or similar.

Comment: ok, thats weird

Comment: Have you tried running the snowsql as the administrator of the windows computer?

Comment: yes, tried the same but not working.

Comment: The Event Viewer on your windoes machine should be able to give you more details on what happened. If you search in the applications window and look for the error who's source is snowsql (I am not sure as I have not seen in before - as that is a guess) does the general info tab give you any more information?

Comment: You can try testing on another Windows machine to narrow down whether it's specific to the machine you are using. Mr. Hoeffer is correct that if there is nothing in the log files, then something is stopping the machine from even launching the application. Is there a proxy, anti-virus, or other security measure in place that might be intercepting the traffic?  Additionally, here is some general documentation to help with troubleshooting: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-start.html